# Reference the current row in the INDIRECT function

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using the INDIRECT function to create a dropdown list in a cell.  The contents of the list will depend on what is chosen in the previous column (same row).

e.g. if in Column A "Cuisine" I have three options in the list (Italian, Chinese, British), I want Column B "Dish" to reflect what was chosen in col A.
So if I chose "Italian" the list in col B will be "Pizza, Lasagne, Macaroni"

I've defined names on a separate sheet and I can get this all working by using the function INDIRECT($A$1) in the data validation command for the cell and using choose from a List.
However when I move to the next row, I want the same functionality.  Is there way to reference the active row - something like INDIRECT ($A$ActiveCell.Row)??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming cells in column `A` has a list of "Cuisine Types", for each of this "Cuisine Types" there is also a Defined Name containing the corresponding options for each "Cuisine Type". With a formula in Column `B` you want to retrieve the corresponding options for each "Cuisine Types".

Try this formula in cell `B1` then copy till last record:

`=INDIRECT( A1 )`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I tried this, but instead of returning the list of corresponding data, it returns the actual value in the previous reference cell.  If I hard code the row number it does work okay, but I need this to apply to all rows.  e.g. referencing my example in my original post, if I choose "Italian" in col A in then use your example in col B, the list displays only the word "Italian".  If I hard ref INDIRECT ($A$1) the list in col B shows all the corresponding Italian dishes.  Are there any other ways to have this variable list build based on my selection in the previous col?

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the dollar signs? If you pull the validation to the next row it should change to A2.